# Use ZeroMQ for forwarding packets in an interface

Tags: networking, zeromq

Is it possible to use ZeroMQ as an intermediate point where different programs can send packets to an `ip:port` combination or alternatively network interface and have ZeroMQ forward any such packets in a specific outbound connection?

So basically I don't want to send data generated by me programmatically but expose some endpoint for other applications to seamlessly communicate as they have always done, but by basically using ZeroMQ as a middleman that will route traffic accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Q** : *"... have ZeroMQ forward any such packets in a specific outbound connection?"*

Given there is a built-in way to avoid using any of the common ZeroMQ high-level Scalable Formal Communications Pattern Archetypes from the arsenal of `{ PUB/SUB | XPUB/XSUB | REQ/REP | XREQ/XREP | ROUTER/DEALER | PUSH/PULL | RADIO/DISH | CLIENT/SERVER | ... }`, there is a chance to use the "raw"-mode, where indeed a socket-FileDescriptor could start to get handled by the ZeroMQ instrumentation `{ .poll() | .send() | .recv() }`-methods.

For a success in your intended use-case to be achieved, yet there will be necessary to carefully follow the published API specification, as the `ZMQ_STREAM` sockets have some built-in behaviours, that need to be reflected in your MiTM-proxy-processing ( strip-off prepended identity, added upon arrival, thread-safety, etc. ).

Anyway, while the core ZMQ-RFC documentation is stable, the API documentation reflects recent changes as the core library still keeps evolving, so keep a close look on what you implement (based on current version) and what to watch for potential further version evolutions and/or discontinued features.

There might be interesting to also harness the `zmq_socket_monitor()` features, as you will be based on connection-oriented `tcp://`-transport class in this scenario.